# How can I make "span id" work with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

How can I make variable `<span id="price"></span>` work with JavaScript?

Have to embed many VARS inside of a long HTML page and need to embed variables in long page.

Can't figure this out.

```js
getPrice = function() {
  var price = Number(document.getElementById("price").value);
  var pout = Number(document.getElementById("pout").value) / 100;
  var sellingprice = price;
  var coop = price * pout;
  var fsbo = price * pout;
  var hret = price * .02;
  var others = price * .06;
  var saves = others - hret;

  document.getElementById("sellingprice").value = sellingprice.toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById("hret").value = hret.toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById("fsbo").value = fsbo.toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById("others").value = others.toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById("saves").value = saves.toFixed(2);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <input id="price"> :Price
    <br><br>
    <input id="pout">%
    <br><br>
    <button onclick="getPrice()"> Calculate </button>
    <br><br>
    
    <span id="price"></span>
    TEST: Price: $<input readonly id="sellingprice"><br>
    FSBO $<input readonly id="fsbo"><br>
    HRET $<input readonly id="hret"><br>
    OTHERS $<input readonly id="others"><br>
    SAVE $<input readonly id="saves"><br>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use <INPUT type=HIDDEN> instead. You can read values off of that. You can't read a value of a span (at least, not as a value.)

Comment: are you trying to display the value price inside a span with an id of price?

Answer (score 1):

You have two elements with the same `id`

```
<span id="price"></span>
```

and

```
<input id="price"> :Price
```

Just because of this whenever you hit calculate it tries to get value from the `span` which is not available and thus returned as undefined and hence all you values may turn out to be `NaN`.

Also `value` attribute is available only to elements that are used for inputs. `span` does not have a `value` attribute for that you might have to look at `innerText` or `innerHTML`.

You must have unique `id` for each element . Below is a working sample of your code with `span` with a different id.

```html
<!Doctype html>
<html>

<body>
  <input id="price"> :Price
  <br><br>
  <input id="pout">%
  <br><br>
  <button onclick="getPrice()"> Calculate </button>
  <br><br>
  <span id="spanprice"></span> TEST: Price: $<input readonly id="sellingprice"><br> FSBO $<input readonly id="fsbo"><br> HRET $<input readonly id="hret"><br> OTHERS $<input readonly id="others"><br> SAVE $<input readonly id="saves"><br>
  <script>
    getPrice = function() {
      var price = Number(document.getElementById("price").value);
      var pout = Number(document.getElementById("pout").value) / 100;
      var sellingprice = price;
      var coop = price * pout;
      var fsbo = price * pout;
      var hret = price * .02;
      var others = price * .06;
      var saves = others - hret;

      document.getElementById("sellingprice").value = sellingprice.toFixed(2);
      document.getElementById("hret").value = hret.toFixed(2);
      document.getElementById("fsbo").value = fsbo.toFixed(2);
      document.getElementById("others").value = others.toFixed(2);
      document.getElementById("saves").value = saves.toFixed(2);
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Hope this helps :)